# Can we use "every inch of" with time, materials, substances, liquids and everything else

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

I know that **every inch** can mean *"completely"* or *"in every way"*, then [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/every-inch) also says that you can use it so speak about *"the whole of an area or distance"* - **every inch of**. Can we use "**every inch of**" to speak about time, materials, substances, liquids and everything else?

- I was inspecting **every inch of her body**.
- Her voice changed **every inch of an hour** as she kept on singing.
- When you fill **every inch of the bucket** with water you have a bucket full of water.
- The molecules occupied **every inch of the surface**.
- **Every inch of her hair** was white.
- The way she spoke to me felt as if **every inch of her words** was a lie.

Comment: It can only be used with things that can be measured in inches.  It can work for the bucket because you can measure depth in inches.  It can't be used with time, words, etc.  It could be used with liquids if they are in a form that can be measured in inches (e.g., on a surface, in a container).  You can measure a surface, a body, and hair.

Answer (score 1):

As fixer1234's comment suggests, "every inch of" only makes sense with things that can be measured in "inches".  So hair, bodies, surfaces, yes, but not time, volume, or abstract concepts.

So you could say "every inch of the bucket was made of wood", because you're talking about the *surface* of the bucket.  But if you want to say it's completely full, you would instead say:

> The bucket was full *to the last inch*

This refers to the space between the surface of the water and the top of the bucket, which can be measured.

Of course, you can say almost anything you want with *creative* writing, to produce a certain effect.  For example:

> Every inch of that hour was layered with grief and regret.

Comment: Your last sentence is marvelous!